# Looking for MS-DOS clip art (possibly Lotus 123?)

Tags: ms-dos

As a kid, I was given a 286 with 640k of RAM and a 20MB HDD, that had Lotus 123 and WordPerfect (v5?) installed. MS-DOS (v3 or v5) only - No Windows. As the machine was very limited, I tinkered and explored whatever I could find.

**I stumbled upon a bunch of clipart images** (I think via Lotus 123) that I would scroll through.

I'm trying to re-discover those images again. All I can say for certain is that they existed. I fired up 123 in Archive.org and DOSBox but either can't find them or they're not there.

Anyone else remember them? Or can point me in the right direction? Thanks!

I can't remember if the images were included with 123 or WP, but I'd say it would be likely. The images were very basic, like line drawings. They may have been B&W (I viewed them on a mono screen).

Comment: This could be a needle in a haystack without more pointers. Do you think the images were stock clip art that came with the package?

Comment: I don’t think either 1-2-3 or WordPerfect came with stock clipart (at least, before WP 6.0); but there were WordPerfect Clipart floppies... See [this set](https://archive.org/details/wordperfect_clipart_gov-edu) for example.

Comment: I never used 1-2-3 or WP, but Lotus Freelance certainly came with a clip art library. But there was nothing much there to interest a typical kid, IIRC.